# Javascipt decimal multiplication and division output

Tags: javascript

Why in the output, the length of decimals differ in these two scenarios?

```
33 * .1 = 3.3000000000000003
```

where as

```
33 * .01 = 0.33
```

Any idea why its like that?

NB: `33` in the above calculation can be any integer

Comment: Note that when you go `33 * .1 = 3.2`. It is due to some numbers not being representable in binary.

Answer (score 0):

> When you convert .1 or 1/10 to base 2 (binary) you get a repeating
>   pattern after the decimal point, just like trying to represent 1/3 in
>   base 10. The value is not exact, and therefore you can't do exact math
>   with it using normal floating point methods.

This is the reason why you end up answer like above.